# ValueError: Unable to create tensor issue for a transformer model

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tensor, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to train a conformer model on audio data and am constantly getting the below error .

"ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`input_ids` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected)."

Although I have activated the truncation and padding values to True in the DataCollator function and in the prepare_dataset functions as shown below, the issue persists.

DataCollator:

```
def __call__(self, features: List[Dict[str, Union[List[int], torch.Tensor]]]) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
    if not features:
        return {}
    # split inputs and labels since they have to be of different lenghts and need
    # different padding methods
    input_features = [{"input_values": feature["input_values"]} for feature in features]
    label_features = [{"input_ids": feature["labels"]} for feature in features]

    batch = self.processor.pad(
        input_features,
        padding=self.padding,
        max_length=self.max_length,
        truncation=True,  # added truncation parameter
        pad_to_multiple_of=self.pad_to_multiple_of,
        return_tensors="pt",
    )
    with self.processor.as_target_processor():
        labels_batch = self.processor.pad(
            label_features,
            padding=self.padding,
            max_length=self.max_length_labels,
            pad_to_multiple_of=self.pad_to_multiple_of_labels,
            return_tensors="pt",
        )

    # replace padding with -100 to ignore loss correctly
    labels = labels_batch["input_ids"].masked_fill(labels_batch.attention_mask.ne(1), -100)

    batch["labels"] = labels

    return batch
```

prepare_dataset funtion:

```
MAX_TRANSCRIPTION_LENGTH=128

def prepare_dataset(batch):
speech, transcription = batch["audio"], batch["text"]

#speech_tensors = [torch.tensor(s["array"]) for s in speech]
speech_tensors = []
for s in speech:
    tensor = torch.tensor(s["array"])[:MAX_SPEECH_LENGTH] if isinstance(s, dict) else torch.zeros((1,))
    speech_tensors.append(tensor)

inputs = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(speech_tensors, batch_first=True, padding_value=0.0)

with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    labels = tokenizer(transcription, padding=True, truncation=True,add_special_tokens=True,max_length=MAX_TRANSCRIPTION_LENGTH,return_tensors="pt").input_ids

with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    input_ids = tokenizer(transcription, padding=True,truncation=True,add_special_tokens=True,max_length=MAX_TRANSCRIPTION_LENGTH, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

return {"input_values": inputs, "attention_mask": inputs != 0.0, "input_ids": input_ids, "labels": labels}
```

Please help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change it as below:

```
tokenizer(sentence_chunks_list, truncation=True, padding='max_length', max_length=512)
```

Answer (score 0):

`padding=True` `truncation=True` will use the default `max_length` 
 try changing your tokenizer parametres to: `padding="max_length"` and `truncation="max_length"`

Comment: "max_length is not a valid TruncationStrategy" in transformers 4.33.0, perhaps earlier versions, too

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(books_dataset["train"].column_names)
```

Note: just make sure you dont have the original columns once you tokenized your data.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the above error but my issue was the labels in my dataset were strings, after mapping them to an int it worked for me .

```
{'label1': 0, 'label2': 1, 'label3': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurred when there were columns in the dataset that the model didn't expect. Deleting or filtering out columns other than the ones the training model needed and then creating a new dataset solved the problem.